# ApplicationHang - PeekMessage

Tags: .net, winforms, freeze, windbg, peekmessage

I am investigating a application hang (winforms). It happens only on the customer machines. They got us a dmp from the frozen process. But i am unsure of how to interpret the data.

I loaded the file into WinDbg.

1. !dlk => no deadlocks
2. !analyze -hang

   FAULTING_THREAD:  00003aec (That's the main thread)
   WATSON_BKT_EVENT:  AppHang
   ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff - 
   EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  cfffffff
   DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:

   Dl Eid Cid     WaitType

   ---

   0   3ae8.3aec COM
   => Looks like a COM Problem on the main thread to me
3. !dumpstack

   user32!_PeekMessage+0x42, calling win32u!NtUserPeekMessage
   combase!CCliModalLoop::MyPeekMessage+0x52, calling user32!PeekMessageW
   user32!PeekMessageW+0x149, calling user32!_PeekMessage
   user32!PeekMessageW+0x149, calling user32!_PeekMessage
   combase!CCliModalLoop::MyPeekMessage+0x52, calling user32!PeekMessageW
   combase!CCliModalLoop::MyPeekMessage+0x52, calling user32!PeekMessageW
   combase!CCliModalLoop::HandleWakeForMsg+0x13b, calling combase!CCliModalLoop::SetPointerInputModeAsAppropriateForQueueAttachmentConditions
   combase!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage+0x49, calling combase!CCliModalLoop::MyPeekMessage
   combase!CCliModalLoop::RevertToNormalPointerInputMode+0x1d, calling combase!CCliModalLoop::IsAttachedQueuePointerMessageReorderingAllowed
   combase!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x262, calling combase!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage
   combase!ClassicSTAThreadWaitForHandles+0x9f, calling combase!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn
   clr!PrepareCriticalFinalizerObject+0x5e, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
   combase!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0x76, calling combase!_guard_dispatch_icall_nop
   clr!MsgWaitHelper+0x8e, calling combase!CoWaitForMultipleHandles
   clr!ThreadStateNCStackHolder::~ThreadStateNCStackHolder+0x1c, calling clr!GetThread
   clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x2e6, calling clr!MsgWaitHelper
   clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x7d, calling clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker
   clr!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x161, calling clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait
   KERNELBASE!CreateEventW+0x8c, calling ntdll!RtlSetLastWin32Error
   :

I am unsure how to investigate/interpret this further. From the stack I would guess a thread where some COM stuff happened is not responding. The call to "PeekMessage" might suggest a broken/not responding message queue. The line with "SetPointerInputModeAs..." also seems highly suspicious to me.

Any suggestions or ideas anybody?

Kind regards

Comment: You'd better capture a series of dumps and then analyze against a few typical hang scenarios (dead lock, slow network, slow database, and more). `!analyze -hang` is less helpful when you are analyzing a managed (.NET) dump. Experts like Tess have more tips for you, https://www.tessferrandez.com/blog/2006/10/13/net-hang-debugging-walkthrough.html

Comment: Thanks. I shall check it out